# Unusual behavior of keyboard language switch

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

Lately I have faced with a problem in changing of the keyboard layout by hotkeys.
First I have [image: EN] on my taskbar. Then I press Alt+Shift and get [image: RU], but I still type in "EN" and additional icon gives menu: [image: menu]

Why do I start to get the additional menu instead of just to switch language? And how can I fix it?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This picture mean switching language within common language group. For example "English (United States)".

That behavior can change third-party software (For example *Steam*).

*Check your software, that may changing keyboard layout*

***OR***

*Remove Russian language group, reboot computer and add Russian language layout again (Wherein check language group - it must be Russian. **Check box** checked must **one only** (in group).).*

[image]

Comment: Reboot solves the problem temporarily even without removing of language group. But your answer contains explanation of causes.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple keyboards installed for Russian language.

Go to Control panel, click on "Change keyboards or other input methods", click button Change keyboards, select US keyboard for Russian language and click remove.

Comment: Nope. Russian language has only Russian keyboard (What's the meaning of multikeyboard per language at all?).

Comment: Strange, I only get the keyboard icon when I have multiple keyboard layouts installed, so I don't know why you get it with only one. Did you try changing to Russian in additional icon menu? For me it worked as persistent change. Also try what MOPTOH says and remove than re-add Russian language keyboard, if it fixes it.